# Uses of AjaxHelper class while using jQuery in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am using `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` across my project with `HtmlHelper` extensions. 
And somehow the advantages of using the `AjaxHelper` has eluded me.(or maybe I'm ignorant)
I was just curious to know what are the uses of the `AjaxHelper` class in asp.net mvc. and whether its really worth incorporating into my project.

Can some one point out some obvious advantages since I find myself comfortable without its use but not-so-comfortable for not exploring it fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AjaxHelper` is the same as `HtmlHelper` except that it pollutes your html code with MS AJAX specific javascript (like `onclick="some very ugly code that performs an AJAX request and handles the result"`). So if you are using jquery, I would strongly recommend you to never think about AjaxHelper. By the way starting from ASP.NET MVC 3, the MS AJAX is replaced by jquery as default framework and the AjaxHelper produce clean markup and handlers are attached unobtrusively.

Comment: Yes, I am using asp.net mvc3.

Comment: Well then the AjaxHelper will use HTML5 `data-*` attributes to indicate unobtrusively the actions that need to be performed. For example it could generate the following link: `<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#foo" href="/Home/About">test link</a>` and then if you include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` to your project it will work.